# In case of diphallia, how is brit-milah affected?

Tags: halacha, medicine, brit-milah

Diphallia is a rare medical condition in which a male infant is born with two penises.

Does brit-milah requires both penises to be circumcised? Is there any reference in the litterature about such an event?

Comment: I recall the Nishmat Avraham discussing hypospadias, wouldn't be surprised if he covers this one too. Fascinating question!

Comment: Robert, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for this indeed fascinating question! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. Remember also to discuss with your own Rabbi and Doctor before making any real-life decisions. Hope to see you around!

Comment: @Shalom Looking at the table of contents, it doesn't seem so, though he does discuss hemophilia (maybe he does discuss it and just didn't put it in the contents, though)

Comment: The Minchas Chinuch would love this: Suppose a baby is born chetzyo eved / chetzyo ben chorin, *and* he has diphallia ...

Comment: בעא מיניה פלימו מרבי מי שיש לו שני ראשים באיזה מהן מניח תפילין א"ל או קום גלי או קבל עלך שמתא "Pelemo enquired of Rabbi, If a man has two heads on which one must he put the tefillin?’ ‘You
must either leave’, he replied, ‘or regard yourself under the ban’." - [Menachot 37a](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l5203.htm)

Comment: But then... א"ל איתיליד לי ינוקא דאית ליה תרי רישי

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Rambam in Mishna Torah Hilchos Milah 1:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2601.htm) says that someone who has 2 Orlos they make the Bris for both on the 8th day.

> ומי שיש לו שתי ערלות, מלין את שתיהן בשמיני.

The [Aruch HaShulchan Yoreh Deah 262:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&st=&pgnum=274&hilite=) and the [Sefer Minchas Ani - Hilchos Milah 13](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_14428_226.pdf) says that although the Bris is done on the 8th day by such a child it would not be done on the 8th day if the 8th day is Shabbos.

Comment: Just to add to this, Rambam also says that circumcising someone with two foreskins wouldn't override shabbat - he records that later in 1:11.