# Woman with 2 wombs in regards to pidyon haben

Tags: halacha, medicine, pregnancy-birth, parts-of-the-body, pidyon-haben

There is a medical condition known as ["Uterus didelphys"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uterus_didelphys). Wikipedia describes it as follows:

> Uterus didelphys (sometimes also uterus didelphis) represents a
>   uterine malformation where the uterus is present as a paired organ as
>   the embryogenetic fusion of the mullerian ducts failed to occur. As a
>   result there is a double uterus with two separate cervices, and often
>   a double vagina as well. Each uterus has a single horn linked to the
>   ipsilateral fallopian tube that faces its ovary.

This is understandably an extremely rare thing. However this raises the question, what would be the din in regards to pidyon haben. If a woman gave birth to a boy from one womb then at a different time gave birth to a boy that formed in the other womb, would the 2nd require a pidyon haben?

Comment: sort of parallel http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22040/759

Comment: Wouldn't it be determined who came out first regardless of two wombs?

Comment: I think the OP is basing himself on the phrase "peter rechem", so there is a valid doubt.

Comment: Yea but by twins in the same womb it is determined by who comes out,classic case: Yaakov and Esav,see the Ketzos who explains Yaakov was the first in the womb,if I remember it correctly.

Comment: If they are in the same womb, then whoever comes out first is first out of that womb.  The question is asking that the first child did not "exempt" the other womb and maybe it will have its own "exemption."  You do not see that from a case of one womb.

Comment: If anyone has a Mamar Mordichai it is in his first Chelek

Comment: @Sam what is there? And where?

Answer (score 15):

Someone asked this question online to Rabbi Yitzhak ben Yosef (*posek* and rabbi of Ramat Gan) [here](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=167313), and he responded as follows:

> בהחלט שאלה נדירה ביותר. 
>   לכאורה כל תינוק הוא פטר רחם וצריכים שני הילדים פדיון צריך לבדוק האם הם פטר רחם דהיינו שלכול רחם יש פתח נפרד.
>
> This is an extremely rare case. Seemingly, each infant is the"opener of the womb" and they both require *pidyon*. It would be necessary to check that each womb has a distinct opening in order for them to be *peter rechem*.

Comment: I can't believe this has actually been asked to a posek +1

Comment: Can you provide some info for who Rabbi Yitzhak ben Yosef is? +1, well done.

Comment: @Daniel I originally heard the question from a Rov who had been asked it on a theoretical level. I think it's common enough that it *could* indeed happen.

Comment: Does he mean separate cervices or vaginae? I suspect the OP's case would only ever happen with two cervices, yet we can test that the Halachik requirement of Yatza Rosho seems to apply when the baby's head leaves the vagina as well (I don't have proof of this, but YD 305:22 sounds that way and it _certainly_ would seem surprising otherwise).

Comment: @DoubleAA, It certainly does sound like two cervices. Also, from the ways he says "צריך לבדוק" makes it sound like it's something that's not so easy to see externally, which I would imagine two vaginae would be, though I'm not so sure.

Comment: @jake I do not agree with your understanding of "צריך לבדוק", since it does not mean this in all the places I saw before

Comment: See also: http://amsgula.online/viewtopic.php?t=132

Comment: @MDjava Dead link. Can you update?

Comment: @Daniel Rabbi Welcher of Queens also got this Shaila and he asked it to Rabbi Zilberstein of Bnei Brak. I believe he also said that they need a Pidyon Haben but I don't remember his logic. Rabbi Welcher shouldn't be too hard to reach if anyone is interested.

Comment: @Eliyahu, I'm sorry I forgot what it was already

Comment: @MDjava Okay. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 4):

the [mishna](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=32&daf=47b&format=pdf) in bechoros states that a child born after a ceaserian birth does not require pidyon (this is codified as halcha). gemara explains that although he **is** considered the opener of the womb, he is not the first child, and he is not considered the bechor for pidyon.

We can infer from here, that any child who has an older brother from his mother, cannot be considered a bechor for pidyon, even if he is a bona fide peter rechem. Which would mean that in your case, the second peter rechem will **not** require pidyon.

Comment: Is the point in the gemara that he's not the first child of this woman or not the first child in that womb? If the first the child in the second womb would not be a bechor, but if the second it would seem he is a bechor.

Comment: @Orion the point is clearly the woman, the idea is that there are multiple measures for bechor, opening the womb is just one of them, the gemara refers to this idea as בכור לדבר אחד.